# laravel 4.2 queries with an encrypted column

Tags: php, laravel, encryption, laravel-4, cryptography

i currently have this code in my controller which display a set of records here is my code

```
public function view()
{
    $title = "View Guardian Information";
    $vPa   = DB::table('dbo_guardianinformation')
                ->join('dbo_cities', 'dbo_guardianinformation.CityID', '=' , 'dbo_cities.CityID')
                ->select('dbo_guardianinformation.ParentAccountID','dbo_guardianinformation.FirstName','dbo_guardianinformation.LastName','dbo_guardianinformation.Roles',
                        'dbo_guardianinformation.Address','dbo_cities.CityName','dbo_guardianinformation.Status','dbo_guardianinformation.EmailAddress')
                ->get();
     //encrypt decrypt algo
    // $sptkey  = md5('sample_encryptkey');
    // $enPass  = rtrim(base64_encode(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $sptkey, $defPass, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB)));
    // $decPass = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $sptkey, base64_decode($enPass), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

    return View::make('ssims.view_parentAccount',compact('title','vPa'));
}
```

my problem is that the column `dbo_guardianinformation.Address`contains encrypted records i currently have no idea on where should i put the decryption code so that when the `$vPa` will be passed to the view it already contained the decrypted  records. any ideas? thanks to anybody who would help

Comment: Seems to me you already have decryption code commented out, at the place where I would think it would make sense to have it, namely, after you fill out `$vPa` but before you build your view. Have you tried to uncomment that code and make it work?

Comment: i had problems when i did it. I thinking of a way, since the `dbo_guardianinformation.Address` column contains encrypted data im trying to make a loop to decrypt all records having no success

Comment: Ok, cool. Can you add *that* code to the question, then?

Comment: i got the answer by using the foreach :) thanks for the advice! :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

#### Indexing Encrypted Data

If you need to [search an encrypted column in a SQL database](https://paragonie.com/white-paper/2015-secure-php-data-encryption#index-encrypted-information) quickly and efficiently, you need to construct a blind index of the data (i.e. store `hash_hmac('sha256', $plaintext, $separate_key_here)` in an additional column) and structure your select queries based on that. (The linked article explains the security requirements.)

This saves you from having to do a `foreach()` loop but, since HMAC-SHA256 is used, it's incredibly unlikely that an attacker with access to the database will be able to tease the plaintext out of the system.

---

That said, there's something else I would like to address:

#### Weak Cryptography

Please don't use the encryption code you included in your question. It's very insecure. [Laravel has its own encryption class](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/security#encryption); please use that instead. It does a lot of the things right that the code snippet you included does not. For example: it provides [authenticated encryption](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/using-encryption-and-authentication-correctly).

```
$sptkey = md5('sample_encryptkey');
```

If you want a modicum of security in your application, don't ever use `md5($string)` to generate a key. This is just a bad idea all around:

- `md5()` returns a 32-char hex string
- Most encryption functions expect a raw binary string
- MD5 is an [incredibly broken hash function](http://natmchugh.blogspot.fr/2015/02/create-your-own-md5-collisions.html)
- To transform a password into an encryption key, you need to use a key derivation function, i.e. **P**assword-**B**ased **K**ey **D**erivation **F**unction #2 with SHA-256 (PBKDF2-SHA256).

Consider, for example, this code instead:

```
define('MY_APP_PBKDF2_ITERATIONS', 86000);
define('MY_APP_KEY_LENGTH', 32); // or 16 for AES-128
// ...
$sptkey = hash_pbkdf2(
    'sha256',
    $your_password,
    $salt, // 32 bytes from /dev/urandom
    MY_APP_PBKDF2_ITERATIONS,
    MY_APP_KEY_LENGTH,
    true
);
```

I've expanded the whitespace here and left some inline-comments below:

```
$enPass = rtrim(                 // Unnecessary, base64_encode doesn't leave whitespace
    base64_encode(
        mcrypt_encrypt(
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, // This isn't AES-256 by the way
            $sptkey,
            $defPass,
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB      // ECB mode is the worst mode
        )
    )
);
$decPass = rtrim(               // Padding oracle attack
    mcrypt_decrypt(
        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
        $sptkey,
        base64_decode($enPass), // No error checking
        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB
    )
);
```

Further reading on the specific issues:

- [`MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256`](https://paragonie.com/blog/2015/05/if-you-re-typing-word-mcrypt-into-your-code-you-re-doing-it-wrong)
- [`MCRYPT_MODE_ECB`](https://filippo.io/the-ecb-penguin)
- [Padding Oracle Attack](https://github.com/keboola/php-encryption/issues/3)

What to do instead (choose one):

- Use [Laravel's encryption features](https://github.com/laravel/framework/tree/4.2/src/Illuminate/Encryption), since you're already using Laravel.
- Use [libsodium](https://paragonie.com/book/pecl-libsodium/read/00-intro.md) (highly recommended)
- Use [Defuse Security's PHP Encryption class](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption)
- When [Halite](https://github.com/paragonie/halite) hits 1.0.0, switch to that (it's basically libsodium for novices)

Answer (score 1):

turns out i with a little tinkering and help from [João Mendes](https://stackoverflow.com/users/694976/jo%C3%A3o-mendes) i had the code like this

```
public function view()
{
    $title = "View Guardian Information";
    $vPa   = DB::table('dbo_guardianinformation')
                ->join('dbo_cities', 'dbo_guardianinformation.CityID', '=' , 'dbo_cities.CityID')
                ->select('dbo_guardianinformation.ParentAccountID','dbo_guardianinformation.FirstName','dbo_guardianinformation.LastName','dbo_guardianinformation.Roles',
                        'dbo_guardianinformation.Address','dbo_cities.CityName','dbo_guardianinformation.Status','dbo_guardianinformation.EmailAddress')
                ->get();

    foreach ($vPa as $key => $dvPa) 
    {
        $sptkey  = md5('this is secret');
        $enAdd = $dvPa->Address;
        $decAdd = rtrim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $sptkey, base64_decode($enAdd), MCRYPT_MODE_ECB));

        $dvPa->Address = $decAdd;   
    }
    return View::make('ssims.view_parentAccount',compact('title','vPa'));
}
```