# Encrypt a string in PHP where the output is URL safe

Tags: php, encryption, openssl

I have a requirement where I need to move a string from one place to another via GET. e.g. 
example.com?string=ENCRYPTED_STRING

Is there a algorithm or some other method to encrypt the string so it is URL safe?

By that I mean it will not have characters like = or & ...

I have tried openssl with AES-256-CBC but no luck.

The data is not overly very sensitive but I would prefer to obfuscate it in someway.

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/function.urlencode.php after encrypt?

Comment: Spot on AbraCadaver. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Oh hey, I've actually done this in one of my applications. My code looks a lot different (because of my custom tools, it's a one-liner), but works basically like this (uses [defuse/php-encryption](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption)):

```
use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;

$url = "/my/endpoint?".http_build_query([
    'something' => base64_encode(
        Crypto::encrypt('my_secret_info', CRYPTO_SECRET_KEY)
    )
]);
// Then you can either use $url in header('Location: '.$url) or in an HTML link safely.
```

Further reading:

- [`base64_encode()`](https://secure.php.net/base64_encode)
- [`http_build_query()`](https://secure.php.net/http_build_query)
- [`urlencode()`](https://secure.php.net/urlencode) (if you don't want to use `http_build_query()`)
- [Why you want authenticated encryption (which defuse/php-encryption provides) rather than just encryption (which OpenSSL's AES-CBC provides)](http://tonyarcieri.com/all-the-crypto-code-youve-ever-written-is-probably-broken)

**Footnote:** If you (or anyone else) want a *short* encrypted URL parameter, [read this answer instead](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32801130/2224584). (I know what's not what you were asking for, but just in case someone finds this question years down the line...)

Answer (score -1):

The code below allow you to encrypt (alpha/num) and decrypt a string. But you need [Mcrypt](http://php.net/manual/fr/book.mcrypt.php) php module installed to make it run.

```
static public function encrypt($text){
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);                                                                           
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "useasuperkey";

    return (bin2hex(mcrypt_encrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv)));
}

static public function decrypt($text){
    $len = strlen($text);  
    $text = pack("H" . $len, $text);
    $iv_size = mcrypt_get_iv_size(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB);                                                                           
    $iv = mcrypt_create_iv($iv_size, MCRYPT_RAND);
    $key = "useasuperkey";

    return trim(mcrypt_decrypt(MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, $key, $text, MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, $iv));
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/32930299/2224584 + http://stackoverflow.com/a/32889090/2224584

Answer (score -1):

I had to do exactly same thing.

My solution was encrypting string with `openssl_encrypt($str, "AES-128-CBC", $key)`.

Then sending the URL using `url_encode($str)`.

Destination page decodes data with `openssl_decrypt($str, "AES-128-CBC", $key)`